# extract specific elements from command output string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, dictionary

i have a command that outputs some data which keeps changing on regular basis.
In this data i need to extract some info and build a dictionary out of it.
I am specifically looking for those node names which have designation as "quorum" and "quorum-manager"

below is the sample output of the command:

```
GPFS cluster information
========================
  GPFS cluster name:         codev.NSD-1
  GPFS cluster id:           8865240017152489758
  GPFS UID domain:           codev.NSD-1
  Remote shell command:      /usr/bin/ssh
  Remote file copy command:  /usr/bin/scp
  Repository type:           CCR

 Node  Daemon node name  IP address   Admin node name  Designation
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   1   NSD-1             192.168.0.1  NSD-1            quorum
   2   NSD-2             192.168.0.2  NSD-2            quorum-manager
   3   NSD-3             192.168.0.3  NSD-3            quorum-manager
   4   NSD-4             192.168.0.4  NSD-4            manager
   5   client-1          192.168.0.5  client-1
```

i was looking for something like below:

```
NSD-1: quorum, NSD-2: quorum-manager, NSD-3:quorum-manager
```

is there a pythonic way to do this. if i have to use regex that might be too cumbersome.
any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Regex are well suited for the task:

```
results = {}
with open('command_output') as fd:
    for line in fd:
        match = re.fullmatch('\s+[0-9]+\s+([^\s]+)\s+[0-9\.]+\s+([^\s]+)\s+([a-z-]+)', line)
        if match:
            daemon, admin, designation = match.groups()
            results[daemon] = designation
print(results)
```

---

Another solution is to create a parser, or just use split:

```
results = {}
with open('command_output') as fd:
    for line in fd:
        node, daemon, ip, admin, designation = line.split()
        results[daemon] = designation
print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python strings' `split()` method on the table rows:

```
nodes = []

for line in table_lines:
    # line = "  1   NSD-1             192.168.0.1  NSD-1            quorum"

    (node, daemon_node, ip, admin_node, designation) = line.split()

    if designation in ('quorum', 'quorum-manager'):
        nodes.append("{}: {}".format(admin_node, designation))

# Print the selected nodes as comma separated list
print ", ".join(nodes)
```

Another way is to use a simple support class for parsing the line and list comprehensions:

```
class NodeInfo(list):
    '''
    This class provides property access to the table columns
    and string formatting for the output.
    '''

    @property
    def node(self):
        return self[0]

    @property
    def daemon_node(self):
        return self[1]

    @property
    def ip(self):
        return self[2]

    @property
    def admin_node(self):
        return self[3]

    @property
    def designation(self):
        if len(self) > 4:
            return self[4]
        return ""

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}: {}".format(self.admin_node, self.designation)

designations = ('quorum', 'quorum-manager')

nodes = [NodeInfo(line.split()) for line in table_lines]
selected_nodes = filter(lambda n: n.designation in designations, nodes)

print ", ".join([str(node) for node in selected_nodes])
```